# Check files on both HDDs on RAID 1 array

Tags: nas, raid

I just set up my LaCie 2big Thunderbolt as RAID 1 array. Is there a way I can look at both HDDs to confirm, that all my data is actually mirrored?

Comment: What sort of RAID 1 are you talking about here? A dedicated RAID 1 external device with built-in hardware & software like OWC's [Mercury Elite Pro Dual](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/Thunderbolt/External-Drive/OWC/Elite-Dual-RAID) or a software RAID created through Apple's Disk Utility?

Comment: The former: [LaCie 2big](https://www.lacie.com/products/big/2big/)

Comment: Looking at the on-line documentation for the LaCie 2big, if you use the software LaCie provides to change RAID configurations (RAID 0 > RAID 1, etc) macOS will jump in and ask you to reinitialize the drive. You can always power down the RAID box, physically remove the drives and install them in separate external housings as individual drives, but this might not work. TBH, just trust the RAID box to keep the mirror identical. I've never needed to actually compare two RAID 1 disks individually to make sure the mirror is working - that's why the device/software does this for you.